# dblfnote.sty with musuos.cls causes unbalanced footnotes

Tags: page-breaking, footnotes, two-column, widows-orphans

I’m the author of [`musuos.cls`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/musuos) and while writing a paper with it I noticed that the [`dblfnote`](http://ctan.org/pkg/dblfnote)-package leads to unbalanced footnote columns

[image]
 You can see that the left colum has one line less than the right one but I’d expect that it is the other way around.

This is the MWE

```
\documentclass[
    twocolfnotes,
]{musuos}

%% class option or this code (which is activated by the options)
%% cause the problem
%\usepackage{dblfnote}
%\setlength{\DFNcolumnsep}{2em}
%\setkomafont{footnote}{\scriptsize}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\Blindtext[2]
\footnote{Vgl. Frank Hentschel: Das Ewig-Weibliche --
    Listz, Mahler und das bürgerliche Frauenbild. In:
    Archiv für Musikwissenschaft 51.4 (1994), S. 274--293, S.286.}
\footnote{Vergleiche S. 4 und Notenbeispiel 4.}
\blindtext[3]
\end{document}
```

I can’t find out why this problem occours …

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems you set `\widowpenalty=10000` in your class, and this penalty also applies to `dblfnote`s footnotes. Resetting the penalty to its LaTeX default value of 150 corrects the "problematic" column break. You could also use the [etoolbox](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) package to patch the `\footnote` command and reset `widowpenalty` only for footnotes.

```
\documentclass[
    twocolfnotes,
]{musuos}

%% class option or this code (which is activated by the options)
%% cause the problem
%\usepackage{dblfnote}
%\setlength{\DFNcolumnsep}{2em}
%\setkomafont{footnote}{\scriptsize}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\pretocmd{\footnote}{%
  \widowpenalty=150% LaTeX default value
}{}{}

\begin{document}
\the\widowpenalty

\Blindtext[2]
\footnote{Vgl. Frank Hentschel: Das Ewig-Weibliche --
    Listz, Mahler und das bürgerliche Frauenbild. In:
    Archiv für Musikwissenschaft 51.4 (1994), S. 274--293, S.286.}
\footnote{Vergleiche S. 4 und Notenbeispiel 4.}
\blindtext[3]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Seems to work, thank you very much! I’d never guessed that …

Answer (score 5):

If you want to change the value of `\widowpenalty` in the footnotes only, you can say

```
\patchcmd{\@footnotetext}{\dfn@latex@footnotetext{#1}}
  {\dfn@latex@footnotetext{\widowpenalty150 #1}}{}{}
```

after having loaded **dblfnote** (requires **etoolbox**).

Note also that the setting `\clubpenalty` in your class is not correct, as LaTeX changes the value of this parameter in some situations and reinstates it by looking at the value of `\@clubpenalty`; so

```
\clubpenalty=5000  % initial value
\@clubpenalty=5000 % for reinstating it
```

is the right way to go.